# Non Anglo and older grad school applicant

Tags: masters, international, age, minority

I am 49 years old, Psychologist with MA in Psych, PhD in Public Health and postdoc at University of Toronto. However,all my academic background here stated is from Brazil and I have been facing some stumbling blocks to enter Academia in Canada. Therefore, I decided to apply for a Masters in Counselling. Would my age and an already extensive academic past with a long research history [non North American] hurt my application? lastly, would I face institutionalized racism due to my non-anglo surname and academic history? My GPA's are: BA= 8.1 ; MA= 9,1 ; PhD= B.
Thank you!

Comment: For a counseling master's? Almost certainly not.

Comment: Did you address the institutionalized racism issue or the old age one? Thank you for helping!

Comment: Anecdotally, age is not an issue for professional master's-level degrees. For counseling in particular, "diversity" should be a plus. *Institutionalized* racism is a problem everywhere.

Comment: I would start with one course as a non-matriculated student or auditor.  This would give you a feel for acceptance level, etc.  Also, it would help you get a foot in the door.

Comment: @aparente001 this is exactly what a professor at USeattle told me last year. But I chose to try the Masters itself. You handed me esome nice food for thought, though.